# jquery fadeIn fadeOut some problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wanted to create some fadeIn FadeOut effects. When pressed button the main id should be removed and hidden content should be appered and wise versa. (sorry for my poor english knowledge) [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgTh2/)

```
<div class='button'>Click me</div>
<div id='main'></div>
<div class='hidden'></div>
```

css

```
#main {
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    background:#95a5a6;
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.button {
    width: 90px;
    height:90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:#e74c3c;
    top:70px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:90px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
}

.hidden {
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    float:right;
    height:250px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:none;
}
```

jquery

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var main = $('#main');
    var hidden = $('.hidden');


     if(main){
           $(main).fadeOut();
           $(hidden).fadeIn();
        }else{
           $(hidden).fadeOut();
           $(main).fadeIn();
        }
})
```

Comment: What is the problem? jsFiddle shows what you are looking for.

Comment: after i press again it is not showing my main id

Comment: I added answer. Hope, I had understood you properly.

Comment: Updated my code — now it is working better. Object will fadein only after previous objected had faded out.

Comment: You might wanna put absolute position on both of them and just fade one in and out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the `fadeIn` method in the `fadeOut` callback

http://jsfiddle.net/jgTh2/12/

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var main = $('#main');
    var hidden = $('.hidden');

    if (main.is(':visible')) {
        main.fadeOut(function () {
            hidden.fadeIn();
        });

    } else {
        hidden.fadeOut(function () {
            main.fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var show = true;
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var main = $('#main');
    var hidden = $('.hidden');


     if(show){
           $(main).fadeOut();
           $(hidden).fadeIn();
           show = false;
        }else{
           $(hidden).fadeOut();
           $(main).fadeIn();
           show = true;
        }
})
```

in the css set .hidden to opacity:0 and remove display:none;

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 1 more variable — flag.

Try this:

```
var flag = 0;
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var main = $('#main');
    var hidden = $('.hidden');


     if(flag == 0){
         $(main).fadeOut('fast', function() {
             $(hidden).fadeIn();
             flag = 1;
         });
     }else{
         $(hidden).fadeOut('fast', function() {
             $(main).fadeIn();
             flag = 0;
         });
     }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgTh2/11/)

As @cgatian suggested, you can use boolean variable, instead of integer:

```
var flag = false;
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var main = $('#main');
    var hidden = $('.hidden');


     if(flag == false){
         $(main).fadeOut('fast', function() {
             $(hidden).fadeIn();
             flag = true;
         });
     }else{
         $(hidden).fadeOut('fast', function() {
             $(main).fadeIn();
             flag = false;
         });
     }
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't a Boolean be more appropriate?

Comment: @cgatian I just suggested, he can use boolean :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to maintain two fadeIn/fadeOut blocks

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    var visible = $('#main');
    var hidden = $('.hidden');
    hidden = hidden.is(':visible') ? [visible, visible = hidden][0] :hidden;
    visible.fadeOut(function()
    {
       hidden.fadeIn();
    });   
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eN6bg/